# PhpStorm Re-commit and push after accidental commit

Tags: git, github, phpstorm

With PhpStorm I know that if you hit <kbd>Ctrl+K</kbd> and click commit, the IDE does only a local commit and the changes are not showed on GitHub.

If I accidentally committed, but actually wanted to commit and push to GitHub how do I go back and do that from my local commit?

Also is there no way to default a commit and push, the tiny drop-down icon is easy to miss click?

Comment: *"Also is there no way to default a commit and push, the tiny drop-down icon is easy to miss click?"* You may have them as separate buttons -- `Settings/Preferences | Appearance & Behavior | Appearance --> Allow merging buttons on dialogs`. Alternatively just use keyboard shortcut for that specific action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by using <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+K</kbd>.  This will open up the Push menu.

You can find this by going to the `VCS` menu, going to the `Git` section and looking at the options in there.